# Equal height Joomla modules to the tallest one in a row

Tags: html, css, joomla, module, height

There are several method on the web to set height of columns equal. One of the best, I think, is "[Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)".

But there's a problem to apply that method on Joomla module structure and I couldn't figure out how to get it to work.

I used **[rounded module chrome](http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_way_modules_are_displayed#What_is_Module_chrome.3F)** (with one main background for module and another background image for inner DIV to wrap modules bottom) on Joomla template source so each module renders this way:

```
<div class="module_menu">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>Main Menu</h3>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><!-- various menu items --></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I use 3 modules in a row that wrapped in a parent DIV.

This is the code:

```
<div style="width:904px; margin:20px; float:left; overflow:hidden; position:relative;">
    <div style="width:904px; float:left; position:relative;">
        <div style="width:904px; float:left; position:relative;">
            <div style="float:left; width:288px; height:100%; margin-right:20px;">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user4" style="rounded" />
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width:288px; height:100%; margin-right:20px;">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user5" style="rounded" />
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; width:288px; height:100%;">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="user6" style="rounded" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally there's css related to the Joomla module's style:

```
div.module-gallery, div.module, div.module_menu {
    width:291px;
    background:url(../images/module-bg.png) no-repeat 50% bottom;
}
div.module div div div, div.module_menu div div div {
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    background:url(../images/module-bg-bottom.png) no-repeat 50% 100%;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    min-height:230px;
}
div.module div div div div, div.module_menu div div div div {
    background:none;
}
```

How can I set modules height equal automate/dynamically with saving Module background style.

Comment: not really an answer but this might help: setting `height:100%` (in CSS) will work only if the parent has height also. even setting `height:100%` to a parent element will make the child `height:100%` work. this is how the lightbox "shade" works with it's height.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look in `templates/system/html/modules.php`.

You can then create a copy of `module chrome` to output your module structure, which would be more beneficial since you code is kinda outrageous to read and isn't very semantic. i.e.

```
function modChrome_myModuleName($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    $doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $css  = ".moduleOuter { your style }";
    $css .= ".moduleInner{ your style }";

    $doc->addStyleDeclaration($css);

    ?>
    <div class="moduleOuter">
       <div class="moduleInner">
        <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
             <h3><?php echo $module->title; ?></h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $module->content; ?>
        </div>
     </div>
    <?php
}
```

You'd then guess call the module with a style, like so:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="myModuleName" />
```

From then on, you'll have a more semantic way of calling your modules and making it easier to get your CSS heights to work.